# How do I install Slick2d using maven?

Tags: java, maven, lwjgl, slick2d

I would like to know how to install Slick2d using maven. I have already installed Lwjgl with maven but I also need Slick2d.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a dependency in maven, it should work the same way u set your maven up with lwjgl. You just have to open your pom.xml which is created by maven, click on dependencies and add the libraries you need: this is how it looks at my project for example:

When clicking add, you just search for slick2d and add the stuff you need.

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150113/ut6ccpii.jpg
(I can't link the image directly cause i dont have enough reputation lol, sorry, Note you don´t need the kyronet stuff)

Hope this helps!